# error: 'template' (as a disambiguator) is only allowed within templates

Tags: templates, gcc

I'm trying to compile some old code (robocup soccer simulation server circa 2003)  with a current c compiler:

`gcc-c++-4.7.2-2.fc17.x86_64`

The function below generates the error in the subject of this question.  Any advice about how to modify the function to get rid of the error would be much appreciated.

```
int getInt( const std::string& param ) const
{ return rcss::conf::Builder::template get< int >( param ); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `Builder` is a class and `get` is a static template method of that class.

The keyword `template` is telling the compiler that `get` is a template method. However, `gcc` is saying that you shouldn't use that keyword if it's not already within a template.

So, removing the `template` keyword should make it work.

Answer (score 1):

From C++03, 14.2.4

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression*, or after *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template.

In your example, `rcss::conf::Builder` does not depend explicitly on a template-parameter, which makes the `template` keyword useless (VC allows it).